# Minimum keystrokes

Tags: optimization

This puzzle is created by me.

---

**String 1:**

```
  This is an example paragraph. It contains multiple sentences.
  In addition to multiple sentences,
  it contains multiple lines, as well as indentations.
```

**String 2:**

```
This is an example paragraph, but changed slightly. It contains multiple sentences.
In addition to multiple sentences,
it contains multiple lines, as well as minor changes, like having no indentations.
In addition to multiple sentences, it also contains a partially repeated sentence.
```

**The puzzle:**

Find the minimum number of keystrokes to turn **String 1** into **String 2**.

**Rules:**

- Your cursor starts at the very end **String 1** (after all characters).
- You may only use the keyboard and arrow keys, no mouse / trackpad.
- The keyboard used should be a standard, U.S. QWERTY keyboard, with no custom keys.
- You may use common keyboard shortcuts, but they count as multiple keystrokes (e.g. `CTRL` + `BACKSPACE` counts for 2 keystrokes).
- A common keyboard shortcut is one that works by default in all major operating systems (so no custom keybindings).
- You may not use keyboard shortcuts specific to the text editor or application; the solution should be generic and applicable to any text editor.
- Your clipboard is empty, but may be used.
- Typing a character counts for 1 keystroke, even if `SHIFT` is used. However, if `SHIFT` is used in a keyboard shortcut, it counts as multiple keystrokes.

Comment: Are the indentations made of 2 spaces or 1 tab?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: @WeatherVane In this case, each indentation is comprised of 2 spaces.

Comment: Upper limit: 443 keystrokes => 155 backspaces to clear string1 + 288 keystrokes to compose string2 (284 keystroke for letters in string2 + 4 uppercase letters that requires shift to be pressed).

Comment: Are you talking about keystrokes as in physical keystrokes, or as utilizing the function of a key? If the former, then holding down the arrow keys allows you to move with only one keystroke, but if the latter, then that is not the case.

Comment: @RobPratt Edit distance may be related, but those methods do not apply here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I initially thought that copying and pasting individual words/character strings might be beneficial, but since every <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> is counted as two keypresses, it would only make sense if the word was very long.

My solution takes **141 keypresses**:

> <kbd>Ctrl + ←</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + ←</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd><space></kbd>
>
>   <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>Shift + Home</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd><kbd>End</kbd>
>
>   <kbd><space></kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd><space></kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>Ctrl + Home</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>Ctrl + →</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + →</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + →</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + →</kbd><kbd>Ctrl + →</kbd>
>
>   <kbd>,</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> <kbd><space></kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd><space></kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
>
>  <kbd>Home</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Down</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>

I could argue that holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and pressing <kbd>→</kbd> five times is really only 6 keypresses instead of 10.  If that's the case, my total count is **136**.

Comment: About the last paragraph rot13(pna lbh hfr nhgbercrng)?

Comment: @WeatherVane It would require awfully precise timing to end up at exactly the right location using autorepeat.

Comment: You can do that with practice. In theory too?

Comment: *down down ctrl-v end* should not work, as there is no new line below the text. Notepad does nothing on the second down-arrow, Chrome puts the cursor at the end of the line. You also appear to be copying the indentation.

Comment: As an alternative *up home del del right shift+down ctrl+(c end v)* should work, and may improve the count.

Comment: Wait what's the `Home` key? I don't think I've ever seen one of those before.

Comment: Sorry, but technically the 5 `CTRL + -->`s count as individual keyboard shortcuts. Great job!

Comment: @CrSb0001 Really?  I probably use it dozens of times a day.  It's with the other cursor-control keys (Del, Ins, End, PgUp, PgDn).  It takes you to the beginning of a line.  Ctrl+Home takes you to the beginning of a document.  Shift+Home will highlight everything between your current cursor position and the beginning of the line.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Ohh that makes sense thank you okay I know what it means now